# Is it possible to redirect a TCP connection based on host name?

Tags: postgresql, http, nginx, tcp, haproxy

What I want to be able to do is connect to a postgres server like this:

`psql -h postgres-a.example.com -p 9000`

That connection should be received by a proxy server (like nginx or haproxy) and it will be redirected to database A because of host name `postgres-a.example.com`. If I use `postgres-b.example.com` and the same port, it should go to database B.

I have been researching this, but I am still not 100% sure of how this would work. I read that the only way to redirect a TCP connection (psql) based on host name is using the SNI header. But I still don't understand if we will need a SSL certificate for this, or if we will need to use `https://postgres-a.example.com` (That doesn't make any sense to me). How it will work?

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: `http(s)` is the protocol of web servers. `psql` presumably uses a proprietary protocol for talking to its database server. `http(s)` sends the host name as part of the initial request, and Nginx understands this protocol which is why it can reverse proxy based on host name. It's entirely possible that `psql` does not send the host name, and in any event, Nginx would not be capable of determining it, so the short answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You will need a certificate for TLS/SSL and you can route the requests based on `req.ssl_sni` to the proper backend.
I'm not sure if psql uses SNI but i think this have you check.

```
frontend public_ssl

  bind :::9000 v4v6 crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy-certs

  option tcplog

  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }

  use-server postgres-a if { req.ssl_sni -i postgres-a.example.com }
  use-server postgres-b if { req.ssl_sni -i postgres-b.example.com }

backend postgres-a
    server postgres-a FURTHER SERVER PARAMS

backend postgres-b
    server postgres-b FURTHER SERVER PARAMS
```

I have created a blog post with a picture for a more detailed description.
https://www.me2digital.com/blog/2019/05/haproxy-sni-routing/